# Checking for any combination of more than one checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have three checkboxes and need to work out what combination of these boxes are checked. I was thinking of doing something like this, but adding an `else if` for every other possible combination.

```
$("#cbOne, #cbTwo, #cbThree").click(function () {
    if ($("#cbOne").is(":checked") == true && $("#cbTwo").is(":checked") == false && $("#cbThree").is(":checked") == false) {
        // do something;
});
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work. Any tips?

Comment: a) you can show the real example on JSFiddle

Comment: b) please, show your html markup.

Comment: Depending what you expect to do regarding which checkboxes are checked or not. You should explain it in question itself

Comment: What about `$("#cbOne, #cbTwo, #cbThree").filter(':checked')`? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr0mbL8z/).

Comment: Do you really need to know about the combination of checked checkboxes? I mean, very often, you can deal with them separately - for example, you have checked `cbOne` and `cbThree`. You check if the first one checked, do some action, check if second is checked, and the same for the third. Can you apply this to you problem?

Comment: can you explain your question further

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ft91arrv/ it doesn't set the variables

Comment: @user3142531 So your issue is regarding variables scope, you are declaring them inside click handler scope

Comment: @GoogleHireMe that didn't work since i need each to change the value of 3 different variables, but i couldn't solve how to reset it after clicking more than one and then unclicking them.

Comment: @user3142531 how values of these _three variables_ are calculated based on selected checkboxes?

Comment: It works with one variable but when i add more than one it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @user3142531 it looks like you don't want to answer my question, but it is your decision. Nevertheless, [here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft91arrv/1/) with my idea what it might be.

Comment: @Regent yea that works, alot better than my sollution thanks.

Comment: How come it shows 0.8500000000000001 when checking the first and third checkbox tho? kinda weird.

Comment: @user3142531 it's normal for non-integer calculations. You can use [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to get rid of this weird output.

Comment: @Regent hmm is it possible without converting it into a string?

Comment: @user3142531 does it matter? If you want to continue calculations, you can use variable's value "as is". If you want to show value to user or to send it via network, you can convert it string with `.toFixed()` and use it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it doesn't work because you have missed closing curly bracket `}` after `//do something` for the `if(...)` statement. 
So, the correct code will be

```
$("#cbOne, #cbTwo, #cbThree").click(function() {
    if ($("#cbOne").is(":checked") == true && $("#cbTwo").is(":checked") == false && $("#cbThree").is(":checked") == false) {
        // do something;
    }//!!! Add this bracket
});
```

Comment: While this is true, I think the OPs pertinent question is how to achieve this logic for all combinations of selected checkboxes.